# Kraken, Dust and Makara

Tags: dust.js, kraken.js

```
<span id='sitemap'> 
    {#footer.sitemaps}
    <a id="{id}" href="{url}">{@pre type="content" mode="json" key="footer.{id}"/}</a>
            {/footer.sitemaps}
</span>
```

In the code, `{id}` is a property of one element in `footer.sitemaps`. I want Makara to get the key value dynamically using `{id}`. May I know how to do that?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out same thing.  Might require custom Dust template helper since the `@pre` tag uses templates precompiled for each locale at build time. 

You can track my question with team here: https://github.com/krakenjs/makara/issues/36

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the discussion around this makara issue: https://github.com/krakenjs/makara/issues/36

Answer (score 1):

Check this: https://github.com/mikesparr/Kraken_Example_i18n_Helper
You can use `@bundleString` helper rather than `@pre`.
So, you can use something like `{@bundleString key="footer.{id}" bundle="your_data_properties_file name"}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the {@provide} tag. Here is an example using yours:

```
{@provide}
    {#footer.sitemaps}
        <a id="{id}" href="{url}">{footerMap[id]}</a>
    {/footer.sitemaps}
{:footerMap}
    {@pre type="content" mode="json" key="footer"/}
{/provide}
```

If your properties file looked like

```
footer.key1=SomeVal
footer.key2=AnotherVal
```

and your footer.sitemaps data object looked like

```
{
    id: 'key1',
    href: 'http://my/url
}
```

The result of running this would be

```
<a id="key1" href="http://my/url">SomeVal</a>
```